# Display the loading gif while the data is loading from excel to json file using tkinter python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

Hello I have a problem with displaying a loading screen in a desktop python app when the data starts to load from an excel file , after I click "load data" the app seems to freeze till it loads the data from excel and converts it into json ,after it finishes it displays the loading gif . What I wanna do is display the loading gif while the data is loading?
thank you guys

Comment: use threading for loading data (and `.after` loops (or only those)), there is plenty of questions on here asking about this that have been answered, either how you need to provide a [mre]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.